# If a Noetherian local ring contains a field, then so does its $\mathfrak m$-adic completion?

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings, formal-completions

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring containing a field. Then, does the $\mathfrak m$-adic completion $\widehat R$ of $R$ also contain a field?

Comment: MSE has rules about what you're supposed to include when you ask a question. The downvotes are probably because you didn't follow them. [This link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) should help you see what you're missing. In short, you should either include your own work/thoughts, or give us an explanation of why the problem is relevant to you. You're clearly not just someone asking users to do their homework, so I didn't vote to close this question, but someone might do so if you don't include some work/motivation.

Comment: There is a ring map from R to its completion. What is the image of its subfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a local ring and $K$ a subfield. Then $1_K(1_K-1_R)=0$ so one of $1_K,1_K-1_R$ is in $\mathfrak{m}$, the other won't be as $(1_K,1_K-1_R)=R$, so one is a unit, either $1_K=0$ or $1_K-1_R=0$, of course it must be the latter.

Now let $R$ be any ring and $I\subsetneq R$ any ideal and $K$ a subfield such that $1_K=1_R$.

The natural map $f:R\to \widehat{R}=\varprojlim R/I^n$ is a ring homomorphism, $\widehat{R}$ is not the zero ring, and $f(1_K)=1_{\widehat{R}}$ so $f(K)$ is a subfield of $\widehat{R}$.

Comment: Why the check that the subring has the same identity?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez if not $f(K)$ may be identically zero